# User-Defined Document Templates

Tags: document-classes

When writing homework sheets, I make use of a template whose preamble incorporates all of the LaTeX goodies that I typically require: packages, page parameters, user-defined commands and environments, etc..  To write a new homework sheet, I simply copy and paste the contents of this template into a new document and begin writing.  This saves me time and helps ensure consistency across all of my many homework sheets.  Unfortunately, this preamble information has grown quite extensive so that I have to scroll down a good deal to even see where my document begins.  Moreover, much of the preamble content will not apply to a given homework sheet, and I don't want to have to weed it out on a case-by-case basis.

My question is:  can this template be implemented more like a true template that can be invoked (like a document class) but whose preamble is otherwise "hidden" from view? Indeed, is this a simple example of a user-defined document class?

Comment: Any style `.sty` file is 'hidden' from the user in direct view as it is stored in the tex tree or in a local user-defined directory, so the answer is yes

Comment: just move the entire preamble into `mystuff.sty` then your documents can be `\docuemntclass{article}\usepackage{mystuff}\begin{docuemnt}...`

Comment: @David Carlisle That worked perfectly.  I wish I'd known about this a long time ago.  My own .sty file...I feel elevated. If you care to post your response as an answer, I'd be happy to make it official.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just move the entire preamble into `mystuff.sty` then your documents can be of the form

```
\docuemntclass{article}
\usepackage{mystuff}
\begin{docuemnt}
 ...
```

That is the basic form of a package, later you can look into defining options and have

```
 \usepackage[something]{mystuff}
```

if you need that, but you can add that later, or you may not need it at all.